# About facebook login on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I notice that some games use Facebook SDK to login to their game. The first time I logged in, it shows a login form and go to their app. After logging out and in again, it doesn't show Facebook login form anymore. If I want to login with another Facebook account, I have to use Facebook app. Why? Why does the logout button of the game not logout Facebook as well? Is it a correct mechanism?

Comment: This is a useful question with a beautiful answer below. If you close it, I'm sure some people will ask it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Facebook.java provided by facebook sdk and then i had changes like this:

```
public void authorize(Activity activity, String[] permissions,
            int activityCode, final DialogListener listener) {

        boolean singleSignOnStarted = false;

        mAuthDialogListener = listener;

      /*  // Prefer single sign-on, where available.
        if (activityCode >= 0) {
            singleSignOnStarted = startSingleSignOn(activity, mAppId,
                    permissions, activityCode);
        }
        // Otherwise fall back to traditional dialog.
        if (!singleSignOnStarted) {*/
            startDialogAuth(activity, permissions);
       // }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below code for logout:

```
private void logout(Facebook facebook) {
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.logout(getBaseContext(), new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.i("System out", "Logout:onComplete:res:state " + response
                    + ":" + state);
            new LoginData(SettingsActivity.this).clearFacebookDataInPref();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            Log.i("System out", "Logout:state" + ":" + state);
            e.printStackTrace();
            exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
            Log.i("System out", "Logout:OnFileNotFoundExce:state:" + state);
            e.printStackTrace();
            exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
            Log.i("System out", "Logout:MalformedURLExce:state:" + state);
            e.printStackTrace();
            exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            Log.i("System out", "Logout:onFacebookError:state" + state);
            e.printStackTrace();
            exceptionMessage = e.getMessage();
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
        }
    });
}
```

if you save the access token and expires on shared preferences, remove/clear on onComplete listener..